# Continuity of ball measure in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $(X,d)$ a metric space and $\mu$ a Borelian probability non atomic measure on $X$.

Fixed $x\in X$, the following application $r\in[0,1]\mapsto\mu(B(x,r))$ is continuous?

where $B(x,r)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<r\}$. I would appreciate some counterexample or some suggestion for the proof.

Comment: What are you having difficulty with? A probability measure is continuous in the sense of increasing or decreasing nested sets.

Comment: No, this need not be continuous.  You could take $X = \mathbb R^2$, $x = (0,0)$,  the measure $\mu$ concentrated on the circle of radius $1/2$.  Then $\mu(B(x, r)) = 0$ if $r \le 1/2$ and $=1$ if $r >1/2 $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $X \subset \mathbb R^2$, where

$X = \{x^2 + y^2 = 1\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$ and $d$ the metric given by that in $\mathbb R^2$ with the Hausdorff 1-measure $\mu$ (divide by $2\pi$).

Then consider the radius function with center at $(0,0)$. The radius function is not continuous at $r=1$.

Comment: Thanks. Some example where $r\in[0,1]\mapsto\mu(B(x,r))$ is not continuous in $r=0$?

Comment: @Tirifilo Yes, I've made it clearer