# Continuity of volume of balls as function of radius (metric measure spaces)

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-measure-theory, optimal-transport

Let $(X,d,m)$ be a proper metric measure space, i.e.

- closed ($d$-)balls are compact
- $m$ is a Borel atomless measure, finite and non-zero on every ball of positive radius

(If necessary, we can assume that $(X,d)$ is complete.)

**Question:** What are (mild) sufficient conditions such that

> for every $x_0\in X$ there exists $r_0=r_0(x_0)$ such that $F_{x_0}\colon r\mapsto m B_r(x_0)$ is continuous on $[0,r_0)$

**Comments:**

1. It is clear that the assertion does not hold on arbitrary metric measure spaces (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2459872/continuity-of-ball-measure-in-metric-spaces)).
2. Furthermore, it is always true that for every $x_0\in X$ the function $F_{x_0}$ has up to countably many discontinuity points (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347969/at-most-countably-many-balls-are-mu-continuity-sets-in-a-polish-space)).
3. Also, $F_{x_0}$ is continuous at $0$, since $m$ is assumed atomless
4. The property is stable under multiplication by $L^p_{\rm loc}(m)$ densities ($p>1$, but maybe not $p=1$), in the sense that if the assertion is true for $m$, then it is true for $fm$ for any density $f$ as above
5. It seems reasonable to expect the property to hold for $\mathsf{CD}(K,N)$ spaces, $\mathsf{MCP}(K,N)$ spaces, and maybe spaces satisfying a Bishop–Gromov-type or a Brunn–Minkowski-type inequality, but I would very much like some simpler assumptions: e.g. **doubling** (and, if needed, **weak (1,1)-Poincaré**, however I do not see why it could be needed).

5'. Bishop–Gromov seems a reasonable assumption because in that case $x\mapsto m B_r(x)$ is continuous for each fixed $r$ (see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04162.pdf), Lemma A.1)

6. A proof/reference for $\mathsf{MCP}(K,N)$ spaces would also be much appreciated.
7. While this seems reasonable to expect, I am not able to show the sought property for the Hausdorff measure on Ahlfors regular spaces (definition [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319955/origin-of-term-ahlfors-david-regular))

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true on *geodesic Monge spaces*.
This includes spaces satisfying the measure contraction property $\mathsf{MCP}$ (hence the curvature-dimension $\mathsf{CD}$ condition for finite-dimension) and also spaces satisfying E. Milman's quasi-curvature dimension condition $\mathsf{QCD}$.

In the following, a metric measure space is a complete and separable metric space $(X,d)$ endowed with a non-zero measure $m$ finite on bounded sets.

**Definition** (Monge space)
A metric measure space $(X,d,m)$ is a *Monge space*
if for every pair of probability measures $\mu_0,\mu_1$ on $X$ with $\mu_0\ll m$

(a) there exists a unique optimal dynamical plan $\pi\in \mathrm{OptGeo(\mu_0,\mu_1)}$;

(b) $(X,d,m)$ has *good transport behaviour*, i.e. $\pi$ is induced by a map: $\pi=T_*\mu_0$ for some map $T\colon X\to \mathrm{Geo}(X,d)$;

(c) $(X,d,m)$ has the *strong interpolation property*, i.e. $\pi$ satisfies $(e_t)_*\pi\ll m$ for all $t\in [0,1)$.

Corollary 2.5 [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00208-021-02331-2) shows

> Let $(X,d,m)$ be a geodesic Monge space. Then, every ball $B\subset X$ is a continuity set for $m$. In particular, for every $r\geq 0$, the sphere
> $$S_r(x):=\{y\in X: d(x,y)=r\}$$
> is $m$-negligible.